# Recursive Complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, time-complexity, computer-science

Can you please help me understand the complexity of this algorithm?

```
int geometric(float *table, int l, int r)
{
    if (r < l) return 1;
    if (r == l) return table[r];

    else { 
        quicksort(table, l, r);
        return sqrt(geometric(table, l, (l+r)/2) * geometric(table, (l+r)/2+1, r));
    }
}
```

Where `quicksort` has a normal time complexity of `O(N log N)`.

Can you tell me which of these options is correct regarding the time complexity of the recursive function `geometric`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we apply [master theorem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regularity-condition-master-theorem/) on it, this yields,

[image]

Actually, I assume that cuz of `float*`, the code snippet is written in C with `math.h`. So, AFAIK in C `sqrt()`'s complexity is `Theta(n)`, so it should be `Cn = 2C(n/2) + n^2*lgn`.

Otherwise, if  it is `Theta(lgn)`,

[image]

where `T` is the `geometric` function.

Almost always at each step `sqrt()` is supplied.

Nonetheless, if we assume `sqrt()`'s complexity as `Theta(1)`, the result points to option `A`.

[image]

---

En passant, `D` option already conflicts with itself since it yields

[image]

Comment: Note that the input to `sqrt` does **not** depend on the number of elements `n`, but on the contents of the table. So it would not make sense to consider its complexity in this context.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog what do you mean by saying _but on the contents of the table_?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog but `sqrt()` is called except for base cases before returning to top of stack always?

Comment: The output value of `geometric` always depends on the **values** in the `table` array, not its **size** (`n`).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog aren't there n values in the table?

Comment: Yes, but what does that have to do with the return value of `geometric`?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Sir, I think I couldn't explain my idea to you. I mean that after returning from every recursive call except for base cases, isn't sqrt called to obtain the returning result?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm trying to say that the time complexity of `sqrt` calls is unrelated to the number of elements in the table.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog actually, I wonder, its reason, why sqrt calls are unrelated to the number of elements in the table.

Comment: Let's do some "average case analysis", by assuming that every value in the table is equal to some number `a`. Can you see that the value passed to `sqrt` will always be `a * a`, regardless of the size of the table?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yes, I can see. Yet, I can't see how many times sqrt calls are applied according to your saying?

Comment: `sqrt` will be called the same number of times as `quicksort`. Again, the difference is that time complexity of *each* `sqrt` call does not depend on the length of `table`, so we should assume it to be `O(1)`.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog let's assume just for example-purposed that n is 100 or changes in every input(different runs) we don't know n, and sqrt's  one operation takes 100^100, so even if sqrt's operation yields huge, it is **constant** since it doesn't depend on table's input size. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Constant with respect to `n`, yes. Also, modern implementations will be *at least* as efficient as Newton-Raphson, if not more. NR has complexity `O(log(b)F(b))` where `b` is the number of input bits, which is ~30 for a `float` (maybe not quite 32).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thank you sir. Now new problem arises for me. If we think it is not sqrt but something else let's call `functionFoo()`. Its time complexity takes 9999!(factorial), but it is **constant**. So it doesn't depend on _**n**_. Our recursive function's complexity is **`nlogn`**. We say that its complexity is  `O(nlogn)`. Doesn't we? **Isn't Big-O in this case fallacious? since we have a really huge value with respect to input size _n_**

Comment: This is far beyond the scope of OP's question, and it would be better read some relevant literature. **All I'm trying to say is that complexity of `sqrt` does not depend on `n`**. Complexity notation is just a theoretical tool which has lots of limitations, and large "constants" such as 9999! are one way to expose them; in the real world, only performance benchmarks matter.